# Storage of android sensor data with foreground service

Tags: android, service, sensors, foreground

I am developing an app that uses a foreground service to monitor and record sensor data on a realm database. A sensors data object which holds all the values is stored every second in the database. I am initializing Sensors event Listeners to listen for sensor events. I am using a channel architecture to send and recieve the sensor data in a stream. The issue i am having is that at some intervals i am finding time skips in the database storage. I have disabled battery optimization for the app, but the issue still persists. The time skipps at every 15-20 minutes or so, but it is sometimes more randomly distributed.

What can be the explanation for this?
Any help is appreciated!

I am attaching some pieces of code execution as well:

```
      accelometerSensorEventListener = object : SensorEventListener {
            override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {

                if (true)
                {
                    for (i in 0 until event!!.values.size) {
                        accelerometerValues[i] = event.values[i]
                        Log.d("DATA" , "accelerometer value : ${event.values[i]}" )
                    }

                    //keep the time stamp for each event
                    if (!acceleratorTimeStampSet) {
                        acceleratorTimeStampSet = true
                        initialAcceleratorTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    }
                    //set the timestamps
```

...
allTimeStamps.add(dateTime.toString())
}

```
                        var sensors = Sensors()
                        var accelX = String.format("%.4f" , event!!.values.get(0)).replace("," , ".")
                        var accelY = String.format("%.4f" , event!!.values.get(1)).replace("," , ".")
                        var accelZ = String.format("%.4f" , event!!.values.get(2)).replace("," , ".")
                        sensors.accelerationXAxisValue = accelX
                        sensors.accelerationYAxisValue = accelY
                        sensors.accelerationZAxisValue = accelZ
                        sensors.timeStamp = allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size -1)

                        writeStringToFile("accel : $accelX\n")
                        data.trySend(sensors)

fun collectSensorDataFromChannelAndStoreToRealmDB()
{
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    var sensorFecthingComplete : Boolean = false
    var sensors = Sensors()

    scope.launch {
        while (true)
        {
            var flowedSensors = data.receive()

            if (flowedSensors.accelerationXAxisValue != null)
            {
                sensors.accelerationXAxisValue = flowedSensors.accelerationXAxisValue
            }

            if (flowedSensors.accelerationYAxisValue != null)
            {
                sensors.accelerationYAxisValue = flowedSensors.accelerationYAxisValue
            }
            
             ...

            if ((sensors.accelerationXAxisValue != null) && (sensors.accelerationYAxisValue != null)
                &&  (sensors.accelerationZAxisValue != null) && (sensors.gyroscopeXAxis != null)
                && (sensors.gyroscopeYAxis != null) && (sensors.gyroscopeZAxis != null)
                && (sensors.linAcceXAxiValue != null) && (sensors.linAccelYAxisValue != null)
                && (sensors.linAccelZAxisValue != null) && (sensors.rotationXAxis != null) && (sensors.rotationYAxis != null)
                && (sensors.rotationZAxis != null) && (sensors.scalarRotation != null) && (sensors.pitch != null) && (sensors.roll != null)
                && (sensors.azimuth != null))
                sensorFecthingComplete = true

            //store the sensor data to realm database
            if (sensorFecthingComplete)
            {
                realmDB = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
                val num : Number? = realmDB.where(Sensors::class.java).max("id")
                Log.d("STORE" , "new ID num : ${num}")
                var nextID : Int = 0
                nextID = if (num == null) {
                    1
                } else {
                    num.toInt() + 1
                }
                if (nextID >= 2)
                {
                    val currentSensor : Sensors = realmDB.where(Sensors::class.java).equalTo("id" , nextID -1).findFirst()!!
                    val currentTimeStamp = currentSensor.timeStamp
                    var previousHour = LocalDateTime.parse(currentTimeStamp , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"))
```

//                        var previousHour = SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss a").parse(currentTimeStamp)
var currentHour = LocalDateTime.parse(sensors.timeStamp , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"))
//                        var currentHour = SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss a").parse(sensors.timeStamp)

```
                    if (currentHour.isAfter(previousHour))
                    {
                        try {
                            realmDB.executeTransaction {
                                sensors.id = nextID
                                if (realmDB.where(Sensors::class.java).equalTo("id" , sensors.id).findFirst() == null)
                                {
                                    Log.d("DATA" , "sensors storing with id : ${sensors.id}" )
                                    writeStringToFile("storing sensor id : " + sensors.id+"\n")
                                    realmDB.insert(sensors)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch(e : Exception)
                        {
                            Log.d("EXCEPTION" , e.message.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {


                       var dummySensors = Sensors()
                        dummySensors.id = 1
                        var now = LocalDateTime.now()
                        var currentTimeStamp = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a")
                        val currentDate = now.format(currentTimeStamp)
//                        var time = SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss a").parse(Calendar.getInstance().time.toString()).toString()
                        dummySensors.timeStamp = currentDate
                            .toString()
                        dummySensors.accelerationXAxisValue = null
                        dummySensors.accelerationYAxisValue = null

                        ...

                        realmDB.executeTransaction {
                            it.insert(dummySensors)
                        }
                    }
                    sensorFecthingComplete = false
                    sensors.timeStamp = null
                    sensors.accelerationXAxisValue = null
                    sensors.accelerationYAxisValue = null
                    sensors.accelerationZAxisValue = null

                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's all types of things that can cause this.  Was the screen off?  Then you went into power saving Doze mode.  A foreground service is not enough to force your app to always be running and not miss events.  If you need that, you need to be whitelisted from power management as well, which has to be done manually by the user (can't be done programatically).

Comment: This sounds like Doze though-  Doze gives apps a brief chance to process data every 15 minutes-ish.  But even when whitelisted that won't be enough to ensure you'll alwyas be running and get data-  Android is just not built to do that.  In fact it's built the exact opposite way.  Even a foreground service will eventually be killed by the OS.

Comment: So how can i whiltelist from power managment in order to not dozeOff?

Comment: Are you sure the Service is not killed? Check if its TID/PID change...if YES: someone has killed it. Howver you can Profle the App using the specific Profiler panel to see all Power/CPU events and know if Doze or other things happens.

Comment: I forced through adb commands both Doze off and App Stand by but the app seems to keep recording data correctly..

Comment: It seems that i solved the problem by implementing a powermanager with a partial wake lock. It keeps using the cpu power even when the sscreen goes of!